# Как определить факт разрыва tcp соединения в boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket?

Tags: c++, сеть, boost, tcp, asio

Пишу небольшой TCP клиент-сервер. На стороне клиента используется boost asio на стороне сервера Qt5. При разрыве соединения (если связь обрывается физически или если приложение закрывается) то Qt сразу это видит и отправляет соответствующий сигнал на который я реагирую.  Но как  реализовать то же самое на другой стороне? При разрыве соединения сокет буста продолжат работать как ни в чём не бывало. Ethernet кабеля давно нет а сокет продолжает отправлять данные =). Режим работы boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket синхронный.

---

#### UPD: проблема решена.

Проблему решил отправляя в методе send параметр boost::system::error_code и затем считывая его. При возникновении проблем с соединением возвращается ненулевое значение. С остальными методами (например available) boost::system::error_code всегда возвращается нулевой, даже при разрыве соединения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, Вам нужно это [boost::keep_alive](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/keep_alive.html)

Comment: Я на него натыкался но так и не понял что он даёт. Попробовал его применить как в примере доках буста, но проблему это не решило.

Comment: @mrFieldy, а Вас не устроило бы следующее решение: Вы получаете дескриптор сокета чз socket.native() (или native_handle), а затем с помощью setsockopt устанавливаете нужную опцию? Извините, мне всего пару раз приходилось работать с Boost.ASIO, но я уверен, что это должно быть связано с опцией KEPP_ALIVE.

Comment: Спасибо. Я думал про нативный сокет, но я не уверен что это заработает на обоих платформах (linux и win) при одинаковом коде. Сейчас я пытаюсь поймать разрыв соединения  через boost::system::error_code но пока все функции что я попробовал возвращают отсутствие ошибок. Как попробую все методы, буду пытатся делать через нативные сокеты (но пока не представляю как сделать это кроссплатформенно).

Comment: @mrFieldy, не думаю, что открою для Вас что-то новое: через дефайны )
> но пока не представляю как сделать это кроссплатформенно